# Can't inject to shared angular component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have 2 Angular applications:

1. Includes one angular component.
2. Consume the component from the first application.

If I run the first app, works fine,
If I run the second app, I have an exception about everything I'm trying to inject into the component from the first app.
Exception:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SampleComponent -> ElementRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SampleComponent -> ElementRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
```

Here is my code:

**First application:**

*sample-component.ts*

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sample-component',
  templateUrl: './sample-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample-component.component.css']
})

export class SampleComponent {
  constructor( private el: ElementRef ) { }
}
```

*index.ts*

```
import { SampleComponent } from './sample-component/sample-component.component';
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

export { SampleComponent} from './sample-component/sample-component.component';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        SampleComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        SampleComponent
    ]
})

export class SampleModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SampleModule,
            providers: []
        };
    }
}
```

**Second application:**

*app.module.ts*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SampleModule } from './../sample-app/src/app'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    SampleModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*app.component.html*

```
<sample-component></sample-component>
```

Comment: Try adding the `SampleComponent` to a `entryComponents` array in the *index.ts* within the `@NgModule` decorator, right below the `exports` array. Something like this: `entryComponents: [ SampleComponent ]`. This has worked for me.